# Numbering Sequence Error on Custom Field - CS Error: Cannot generate the next number for the sequence

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created a custom screen called "Proof of Delivery" (Screenshot 1). The "POD Nbr" field on the Proof Of Delivery screen needs to follow a numbering sequence. For the numbering sequence I have created a preferences screen for the Proof of Delivery called "Proof of Delivery Preferences" (screenshot 2) with a selector field which is populated from the numbering sequence that has been set up on the "Numbering Sequences" (CS201010) screen (Screenshot 3). The selector on the Proof of Delivery Preferences screen is then used in the DAC to set the numbering sequence for the POD Nbr field.

**Screenshot 1: Proof of Delivery Screen**

[image: Screenshot 1: Proof of Delivery Screen]

**Screenshot 2: Proof of Delivery Preferences Screen**

[image: Screenshot 2: Proof of Delivery Preferences Screen]

**Screenshot 3: Numbering Sequence setup**

[image: Screenshot 3: Numbering Sequence setup]

**Proof of Delivery Preferences DAC:**

```
    [PXCacheName("ProofOfDeliveryPreferences")]
    public class ProofOfDeliveryPreferences : IBqlTable
    {
        #region SequenceNumber
        [PXDBString(255, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sequence Number")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<Numbering.numberingID>),
                typeof(Numbering.numberingID),
                DescriptionField = typeof(Numbering.descr))]
        public virtual string SequenceNumber { get; set; }
        public abstract class sequenceNumber : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<sequenceNumber> { }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Proof of Delivery DAC (POD Nbr field):**

```
        [PXDBString(255, InputMask = "", IsKey = true)]
        [AutoNumber(typeof(ProofOfDeliveryPreferences.sequenceNumber), typeof(ProofOfDelivery.createdDateTime))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "POD Nbr.")]
        public virtual string Podnbr { get; set; }
        public abstract class podnbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<podnbr> { }

        #endregion
```

When I try to add a new Proof of Delivery, I get an error related to the numbering sequence setup as follows:

[image: Screenshot 4: Numbering Sequence error]

How can I fix this error in order for the screen to be able to generate its numbering sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that in the graph you have the PXSetup view defined for the preferences where the numbering sequences is defined.

In your case it should be:

```
PXSetup<ProofOfDeliveryPreferences> proofSetup;
```

This is easily identifiable as in the selector you have the  placeholder instead of the new number symbol defined in the numbering sequence.